# Do we need to ioremap for memmap reserved memory chunk ?

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel

I reserve the memory chunk using a `memmap=8G$4G` linux kernel boot parameter.

Is it needed to `ioremap` this memory ?

`ioremap` man pages say :

> ioremap performs a platform specific sequence of operations to make
>   bus memory CPU accessible via the readb/readw/readl/writeb/
>   writew/writel functions and the other mmio helpers. The returned
>   address is not guaranteed to be usable directly as a virtual address.

So if i can't use the returned address of `ioremap` as a virtual address for directly addressing the memory, then a broader question is when should we `ioremap` the memory ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to `ioremap` this region to access it. The kernel does not set up the Page Directory Entries for this memory region as you instructed the kernel to ignore this region.

The addresses returned by `ioremap` may not be used directly if you remapped the addresses of `io-port` address space. When you remap the addresses from the `memory` address space then it is OK to use them directly.

However, please take look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37729/how-can-i-reserve-a-block-of-memory-from-the-linux-kernel

Comment: pls read the comments on your question link by reading all the responses to this question. I have explained the issues i see with this. If you have more information pls share. Thanks.

Comment: @JayD Are you talking about intel-based architecture, or you like your solution to be portable across different processor architectures? If the former is true then take a look at the kernel code and see what the kernel does for `ioremap` of memory and why you can use directly the address returned in this case (just as I did providing you the answer). In the latter case this is definitely not a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience with reserving ( or blocking) the memory is as followed.

> if you are trying to reserve a particular volume of memory you may have to remap the already existing memory map provided by BIOS.

If your system doesnt enable you to do so then you will have to identify which area is free in the BIOS provided memory map and only that can be reserved.